# Table text alignment problem

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a problem with alignment in the table.

I want to vertically center alignment the first column of a table like 'After' image. 
In the code I uploaded, the text in the first column is at the top, like the 'before' image.

Where should I change?

Before

[image]

After

[image]

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.3cm}|p{4.6cm}|p{4.6cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Model}}   \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}             
& \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}p{4.75cm}|}{\textbf{A}} 
&\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}p{4.75cm}|}{\textbf{B}} \\  \hline
Description &  
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]\item \end{itemize}    &    
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]   \item   \begin{itemize}   
\item 
\item  \end{itemize}  \end{itemize} \\ \hline
Advantage   &  
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]   \item  \end{itemize}  &    
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]   \item  \begin{itemize} 
\item \end{itemize}
\item\end{itemize}   \\ \hline
Disadvantage   &          
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]   \item 
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]   \item \end{itemize}  \end{itemize}    &   
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]   \item   \end{itemize}    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{Models}
\label{tab:model}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code snippet a compilable document.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. Contents in the first row is horizontally centered. What is your problem?

Comment: @Zarko I compile with the code on this page. However, pdf looks like 'before' image. I want to change the code to 'after' image, the first row to center alignment.

Comment: Sorry, but the first row is centered! You probably means that contents in the first column should be vertically centered?

Comment: @Zarko Sorry, that's right. I mean vertically centered.

Comment: Please, than edit your question and clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you seem to confuse the term "row" with "column". Contents of the first row is centered vertically as well horizontally. Based on the second image follows, that you like to have vertical centered content of cells in the first column. Typographically this is not good idea, better is to have table as is shown on the first image.

However, if you persist on you desired design, one way is to use `\multirow` cells in the first column. This require manual setting maximal number of lines in adjacent cells:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell} % new
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries} % new
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}      % new
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{% new
    \setlist[itemize,1]{nosep,     
                       leftmargin = *         ,
                        label     = $\bullet$ ,
                        before    = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                        after     = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                        }
    \setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
                           }% end of AtBeginEnvironment

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.3cm}|p{4.6cm}|p{4.6cm}|}
    \hline
                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Model}}       \\ \cline{2-3}
                & \thead{A}
                    & \thead{B}                             \\  \hline
\multirow{4}{=}{Description}     
                &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item item
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                        \item item
                            \begin{itemize}
                            \item subitem
                            \item subitem
                            \end{itemize}
                        \end{itemize}                       \\ \hline
\multirow{3.4}{=}{Advantage}       
                &   \begin{itemize}  
                    \item item
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                        \item  item
                            \begin{itemize}
                            \item  subitem
                            \end{itemize}
                        \item item
                        \end{itemize}                       \\ \hline
\multirow{2.4}{=}{Disadvantage}    
                &   \begin{itemize}  
                    \item item
                        \begin{itemize} 
                        \item subitem 
                        \end{itemize}  
                    \end{itemize}    
                    &   \begin{itemize}   
                        \item item   
                        \end{itemize}                       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{Models}
\label{tab:model}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

As you can see, table is wider than `\textwidth`. You need to appropriate adjust columns' widths.

*Note:*
content in cells in a row are vertically aligned to their baseline. As you write your table with column specifiers `{m{...} p{...}p{...}` are baseline of the first cell is at vertical center of the text in this cell and it is aligned to the baseline of the second and third cells, which are on the top of cells. In case that in the first row you have text with three lines, the middle line will be aligned with the top of other cells' contents.

**Addendum:**
in case, that you use Overleaf service you can experience problems with `multirow` package. Temporary it doesn't use its recent version, which is considered an above MWE. Problems you can solve with the following changes:

`\multirow{3.4}{=}{Advantage}` replace with `\multirow{3}{=}[-1ex]{Advantage}`

`\multirow{2.4}{=}{Advantage}` replace with `\multirow{2}{=}[-1ex]{Advantage}`

Hopefully Overleaf will upgrade its packages repository in near future and will original MWE work as expected and tested with recent MikTeX.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I modify row to column.

Comment: @Sean, now is more important if the answer solve your problem.

Comment: I copied and compiled your code, but it looked different from the picture of your result.
Still not centering vertically (I'm using overleaf)
And if you type a letter, the character goes out of the border.

Comment: @Sean, this should not be a case. Only difference is that code doesn't produce red lines indicating page layout. However, overleaf has old version of `multirow` package, so it screw up results int he first columns. Try to remove decimals in number of rows in `multirow` cells ; `\multirow{2.4}{=}{ ...` replace with `\multirow{2}{=}{...`

Comment: Thank you. The method you told me did not work, so I temporarily adjusted it to manual using vspace.

Comment: @Sean, as you wish. Of course, my solution perfectly work. So your claims is incorrect.

Comment: I will try again. Thank you very much! I'm a latex beginner so I might have made a mistake.